# About NFS on embedded system

Tags: embedded-linux

I'm working on an Linux embedded system and I'm using NFS to test and make my trials.
As boot device I'm using an SD card (eMMC as boot device is also possible).
Since I arranged my SD Card to store both boot and filesystem to allow the system to work with the whole system on SD Card, I'd like to know what's the minimum requested on SD Card to boot in NFS mode.
Does in NFS mode it's used uboot only from the SD Card?
Kernel (ZImage) and DTB files are necessary on the SD Card used as boot device?
And filesystem must be on the SD Card too?

Paolo

Comment: *"what's the minimum requested on SD Card to boot in NFS mode"* -- To use NFs as the root filesystem, the board must be able to boot the Linux kernel.  That means that a kernel image and DT blob must be loaded into main memory.  But if you also have a TFTP server, then that kernel image and DT blob could be downloaded by U-Boot.  So the minimum requirement is the ability to boot U-Boot from local storage,, and then everything else can be from the network.

Comment: I understand the question to be. "what is the minimum required size for my system". Because I don't know what system (kernel version/distribution/applications) you have I can not answer the question. 
I can tell you it is common to put embedded linux installs on 16Mb to 64 Mb cards. And if you are willing to net boot, you only NEED uboot (2 or 4 Mb)  or less

Comment: John b, sorry, you're right, My question is not so clear, but it was referenced to what's the minimum files requested. Thanks to sawdust that crearly explained the boot and NFS mechanism.